# add post result from one query to an existing column/row in same table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, insert

Im trying to store the result of a secondary, sequential post into the results of a first query already stored in my table.

First query:

```
// Get values from form 
 $monto=$_POST['monto'];
 $personas=$_POST['personas'];
 $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
 $giro1=$_POST['giro1'];
 $giro2=$_POST['giro2'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(monto, personas, ciudad, giro1,           giro2)VALUES('$monto', '$personas', '$ciudad', '$giro1', '$giro2')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

The value of giro2 is to be captured based on the selection if giro1 but should all end up in same row in same table as:

```
uid | monto| personas| ciudad| giro1| giro2 
--------------------------------------------
1   |  5   |   1     |   NY  | food | Null
```

second form POST:

```
// Get values from form 
$giro2=$_POST['giro2'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (giro2) VALUES ('$giro2') SELECT uid FROM     $tbl_name WHERE uid = 1";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

In the end I get ERROR or if I remove SELECT ... I get giro2 stored in uid=2

How can I save the second post into same row and correct column?

Comment: show us what the real errors are http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php  and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - basically, your query failed.

Comment: See @Nelson Teixeira Solution. That is all you need. **UPDATE** not **INSERT** because "Inserts" create new Rows, "updates" updates already existing Rows.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: The only ERROR is the output of the code itself, not on the serverside.  The echo "ERROR"; result is what is displayed. I was using another sample of code PDO style, but would not store to db and would not give error either. Just blank everything. And yes I am a beginner who doesnt know the difference between PHP3,4,5,6,7. Just with a great Idea to materialize. I have tried too hire programmers but they are all too busy to help. LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has 2 sql statements in the same line

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (giro2) VALUES ('$giro2') SELECT uid FROM     $tbl_name WHERE uid = 1";
```

you have to divide it in two. First you get the uid, the you use the value to update the table with UPDATE, not with INSERT. INSERT inserts new values in the table, UPDATE, as the name says, updates old ones.

However you already seem to know that the number of the uid you want to update is 1. Then the only thing you need is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE "$tbl_name" SET giro2 = "$giro2" WHERE uid = 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Right Solution however, **WHERE uid=1** might not be so explicit because he may not know how to obtain the **last insert id** which is required for a precise Update. Had you added how to access the uid, it would have been more than just Right: PERFECT.

Comment: I'm considering that he's a newbie that has to go one step at a time and also study a bit to find things. If I told him how to get the uid maybe it would be harder for him to understand the update thing at this point.

Comment: And that also makes You not only a Good Coach but also Highly Skill Teacher. I agree... you are perfectly right... he needs that one extra step ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using last insert id in various combinations or versions but to no avail.  The PHP version I am using is the only coding I have found that actually turns a result for my queries, given my inexperience.  printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysql_insert_id()); after the first query was saved. Then I tried to use it in the second query and to no avail.

Comment: I tried Nelsons Code but gave me errors. Instead I used     $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET giro2='$giro2' WHERE uid= 1";       where only if my last id were =1 otherwise I still need to implement last insert id. For that, I need help